# Create array of last 12 months based upon current date in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, date

This is the currentdate i.e today's date

```
  var currentDate = new Date();
```

Let's say today's date is `Sat Mar 21 2015 17:19:15 GMT+0530`. I extracted the month from the date using the below code

```
var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var month = monthNames[currentTime.getMonth()];
```

In my case month = `MAR`

Based upon the current `month` I want to create an array of last 12 months in increasing order from `month-12` up to the present month that is `MAR`. The array must like this if current month is `MAR`

```
  date = ["APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR"];
```

How to get a dynamic array based on current date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `monthNames.slice(currentMonth).concat(monthNames.slice(0, currentMonth));`

Comment: @Yoshi Assuming `var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;` that is very nice.

Comment: @GregL You're right! Missed that ;)

Comment: That is not my issue. I have edited my question. Please read it again. I want an array based on current month

Comment: @Yoshi your write. I have changed it back. And my question is not about date format . The question is that based upon the month I have to create and array of last 12 months.

Comment: @rjirji Simply drop the step where you convert the numeric month to a string, it's not needed. Demo: http://jsbin.com/yasujeqoqe/1/